# Firebase: How to implement "take action only when another device is online"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am implementing a communication app using Firebase Real-time database with certain game kinds of features which needs both the users online. Consider user `A` and `B` are communicating and there are certain actions `A` can take only if `B` is also online(B is connected to Firebase Real-time Database). How can I implement this?

**Things I have already tried**

1. I have a node called `user/user_id/online`. I update it whenever the
   database is online and I remove it on disconnection using `onDisconnect` function.
   Problem with this logic is firebase server does not execute
   `onDisconnect` logic till server-side socket times out which most of
   the time takes more than a minute(Even calling goOffline on internet error also takes more than a minute) but in my case, only 1 to 3
   seconds latency is allowed.
2. I have a node called `user/user_id/last_online` and update it once
   in every 2 seconds and the user `A` will keep checking user `B's` last
   online time before taking any action. Problem with this logic is, this will drastically increase data download rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to have the best approach with built-in primitives, i.e. Firebase's presence system. One note on the `onDisconnect` though: it will only take that long to detect a dirty disconnect (app crashes, network connection lost, etc). In the case of a clean disconnect (app is closed), the `onDisconnect` should fire almost immediately.

If the way the `onDisconnect` behaves is not good enough for your needs, you will need to implement the rest inside your app.

The first thing that came to mind is an active keep-alive, which seems to be what you already use in #2. Given that you want a latency of at most 3 seconds, your 2 second keep-alive ping seems like a reasonable interval.

This will indeed increase your bandwidth usage. Given your use-case and the way the platform works, I don't see any other way to implement it though.

Comment: Thank you, Frank. Does calling `goOffilne` call `onDisconnect` immediately? I tried creating a network connection state listener and called `goOffline`  on network lost but `onDisconnect` did not fire. I feel on network lost it's already considered as `dirty disconnect` so `goOffline` adds no value. Am I right?

Comment: Closing the page definitely fires immediately in my experience. I'm not sure about `goOffline()`, because I never use it (I don't have a use-case for explicit connection management like that). But if you have code that doesn't work the way you expect it to, update your question to include the [minimal complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to mention that I am working on an Android app. According to me `goOffline` needs an internet connection to work so won't support my use case.